# How to set an auto minimum width on column with css?

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

I am trying to create table where two of the columns are the smallest width needed to contain the content, and the third column would be as wide as possible. I do know how wide the two columns will be and they wont change that much, but I would rather as little hard-coded widths as possible.

Here is what I got:

```
​<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" style="width:auto;">
            123 123 123 123 123
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            bla bla
        </td>
        <td align="right" style="width:auto;">
            hello
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

The first and last columns take more space than needed causing the middle column to not look centered. Is there a way to do this or should I just hardcode the widths?

Edit: The answer is so simple. Here is the full answer in case it helps anyone else:

```
​<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" style="white-space:nowrap;">
            123 123 123 123 123
        </td>
        <td align="center" width="100%">
            bla bla
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            hello
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have your table set to 100% width.. it must expand something :-)

Comment: yes, it is giving the extra space to all three columns, but I want only the middle column to get the extra space.

Comment: set your middle column to 100% width :-)

Comment: yup... I thought I was missing something simple. I was thinking I needed to do something to the other two columns, instead of simply make the middle column expand fully.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use percentages for widths?  Width 100% expands the columns and if the columns don't have a set width, it adds the left over amount in proportion to the rest of the columns.